# How to configure port server in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to configure the server port in config/boot.rb file. Looking at lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb we have this:

```
125       def perform
126         set_application_directory!
127         Rails::Server.new(server_options).tap do |server|
128           # Require application after server sets environment to propagate
129           # the --environment option.
130           require APP_PATH
131           Dir.chdir(Rails.application.root)
132           server.start
133         end
134       end
135 
136       no_commands do
137         def server_options
138           {
139             user_supplied_options: user_supplied_options,
140             server:                @server,
141             log_stdout:            @log_stdout,
142             Port:                  port,
143             Host:                  host,
144             DoNotReverseLookup:    true,
145             config:                options[:config],
146             environment:           environment,
147             daemonize:             options[:daemon],
148             pid:                   pid,
149             caching:               options["dev-caching"],
150             restart_cmd:           restart_command
151           }
152         end
153       end
```

How can I configure Port from config/boot.rb then?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to monkey patch boot.rb to change port, but no luck. Upon browsing I learned that Rails 5 comes with puma, which is configured in config/puma.rb. You can change the default port number in that file, or override it by setting the PORT environment variable before starting rails.

```
config/puma.rb
# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; 
# default is 3000.

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
```

I hope this helps.